# Что делать при массовом неправильном использовании метки?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Есть метки, у которых есть описание или руководство по использованию, но они все равно используются не по назначению. Для некоторых меток это носит массовый характер, например, [flex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) или [select](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select).

Что делать при обнаружении таких меток, беспощадно править все вопросы или поднимать обсуждение на Мете для каждой метки в отдельности?

В случае метки [select](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select), описание метки появилось после того, как она активно использовалась для вопросов, относящихся к *HTML*-элементу [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select). Что делать в таком случае?

Comment: Жечь, детка, жечь!

Comment: flex — это 37 вопросов, можно и переназначить на flexbox.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, почему [tag:удаление-метки]?

Comment: @Qwertiy, мне показалось что удаление-метки подходит для случаев когда чешется огнемет

Answer (score 15):

### Flex

Переименовать [flex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) в [apache-flex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-flex). Неправильные использования заменить на [flexbox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox). Будем реалистами: про Apache Flex мало кто слышал, а популярность CSS Flexbox будет только расти. Количество меток это явно подтверждает.

### Select

Метка [select](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) ужасна, и вряд ли с ней можно сделать что-то осмысленное. По-хорошему надо бы разделить её на версии из HTML, SQL, LINQ и так далее, но заставить участников правильно расставлять метку будет невозможно.

Совсем сжигать метку при этом будет вредно, потому что в совокупности с другими метками [select](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) вполне может использоваться. Так что, хоть это и мета-метка с претензией на конкретное SQL-ное значение, и сжигание, и преобразование не улучшат, а скорее ухудшат поиск информации на сайте.

Так что пусть будет.

## Опыт большого брата

Для статистики: на Мете большого SO есть соответствующее предложение про [переименование метки flex](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319516). Оно написано от лица того, кто денно и нощно исправляет метку flex на flexbox. Предложение заметно заплюсовано (+17/−3), но действия не предприняты. Так как у нас нет желающих круглосуточно сидеть и исправлять метки на всех поступающих вопросах, то будет рационально переименовать метку в соответствии с моим предложением.

По метке select также несколько обсуждений, условно принятым можно считать [предложение разделить метки](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269215), однако если действия и совершались, их было недостаточно для приведения использования метки в порядок. В принципе, если есть желающие привести в порядок 300 вопросов, то можно пойти по сложному пути, а метку select впоследствии занести в чёрный список.

Comment: Достаточно четырех голосов и отсутствия других ответов, чтобы считать, что сообщество согласно с этим решением?

Comment: @Dmitry Лучше сначала выждать пару недель: ответ дан только вчера.

Comment: @Dmitry Добавил информацию по большому СО.

Comment: @AK Ждать пару недель не имеет смысла, потому что вопрос будут активно посещать в первый день, потом вяло ещё пару дней, потом про него все забудут. Если не торопиться, то можно подождать неделю максимум.

Comment: @Dmitry, во время прошлого массового увлечения огнеметом мы считали баланс +8 кажется достаточным мнением сообщества

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Если бы я не принялся редактировать этот ответ, а предусмотрительно настроенные в чате во время моего председательства фиды не завалили чат, у этого ответа было бы 4 плюса. Нужно принимать во внимание не конкретные числа, но и активность юзеров.

Comment: @Squidward, да, разумеется. Главное чтоб кому-то хотелось жечь, а оправдание найдется)

Comment: Эх, по ходу мне надо было задать подобный вопрос до того, как исправил пару десятков вопросов с неправильным использованием метки flex. :-)

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko Пара десятков — не пара сотен. 

Comment: Давайте сделаем это!